# UITextView customization

Tags: ios, uitextview

I want to format the test in my textview, some texts in bold some thing in italic like that. Is it possible for uitextview?
Right now I'm using webview with HTML strings.
eg:

```
<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">h3 {color:white;} p {color:pink;} p {text-align: center} p {font-family:helvetica;font-size:20px;}</style></head><body>\
                                         <h3></h3>\
                                         <p><b>some text </b></p>\
                                         <p>Short some text</p>\
                                         <p>Child  Infusion  7.5 to 15 mg/kg/hr<br>ie 7.5 to 15 times weight per hour</p>\
                                         <p>Adult  Infusion  3 to 12 mg/kg/hr<br>ie 3 to 12 mg times weight per hour</p>\
                                         </body></html>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use  NSAttributedString, Set Text Font, Foreground And Background Colors, StrikeThrough And Shadow etc..

Attributed strings make an association between characters and their attributes. Like NSString objects, there are two variations, NSAttributedString and NSMutableAttributedString.
Although previous versions of iOS supported attributed strings, it wasn’t until iOS 6 that controls such as buttons, labels, textfields and textviews defined a property to manage attributes.
Attributes are applied to a range of characters, so you can for example, set a strikethrough attribute for just a portion of a string. It’s also important to note that the default font for attributed string objects is Helvetica 12-point. Keep this in mind if you set the font attribute for a range other than the complete string.
The following attributes can be set with attributed strings:
NSString *const NSFontAttributeName;
NSString *const NSParagraphStyleAttributeName;
NSString *const NSForegroundColorAttributeName;
NSString *const NSBackgroundColorAttributeName;
NSString *const NSLigatureAttributeName;
NSString *const NSKernAttributeName;
NSString *const NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName;
NSString *const NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName;
NSString *const NSStrokeColorAttributeName;
NSString *const NSStrokeWidthAttributeName;
NSString *const NSShadowAttributeName;
NSString *const NSVerticalGlyphFormAttributeName;

here are some examples

```
//-----------------------------
// Create attributed string
//-----------------------------
NSString *str = @"example for underline \nexample for font \nexample for bold \nexample for italics";
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:str];

// Add attribute NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName
//[attributedString addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUnderlineStyleSingle] range:NSMakeRange(12, 9)];
[attributedString addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUnderlineStyleSingle] range:NSMakeRange(12, 9)];

// Set background color for entire range
[attributedString addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName
                         value:[UIColor yellowColor]
                         range:NSMakeRange(0, [attributedString length])];


// Create NSMutableParagraphStyle object
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraph = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraph.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

// Add attribute NSParagraphStyleAttributeName
[attributedString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraph range:NSMakeRange(0, [attributedString length])];



// Set font, notice the range is for the whole string
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18];
[attributedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:NSMakeRange(35, 4)];



// Set font, notice the range is for the whole string
UIFont *fontBold = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:18];
[attributedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:fontBold range:NSMakeRange(53, 4)];

// Set font, notice the range is for the whole string
UIFont *fontItalics = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Oblique" size:18];
[attributedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:fontItalics range:NSMakeRange(71, 7)];



// Set label text to attributed string
[self.mytextView setAttributedText:attributedString];
```

`